# Winsock Received buffers caracters

Tags: c++, buffer, winsock

I am currently trying to create an application to send messages from a server to a client after initiating the connection by sending filters from the client to the server (like a subscrition). The entire application is done but I found out that the messages I send contain special caracters and dont have the size they are supposed to have. Here is an example with the filters (which are 3 letter words) that the server receives:

```
Client connected!

Bytes received: 3
REceived Filters:ATL����������������������
```

Although it says that 3 bytes were received, it prints 25 caracters.

Here is the server side part of the code I use to receive the filters:

```
// Receiving and sending data on server socket

    int iSendResult;

    // buffer for received msg
    char recvbuf[3];
    int recvbuflen = 3;
    int compteurSend = 1;

    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("\nBytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("REceived Filters:");
            std::cout << recvbuf << "\n" << std::endl;
        }

          ...... rest of the code to send back data ......
```

And here is the client side part of the code I use to send te filters:

```
    // Sending and receiving data

        // buffer for sending filters
        const char* sendbuf = "ATL";
        int sendbuflen = strlen(sendbuf);

        // buffer for receiving
        char recvbuf[4000];
        int recvbuflen = sizeof(recvbuf);

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, sendbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Filters Sent: " << "'" << sendbuf << "'" << " containing " << iResult << " bytes\n\n";
```

While the output of the cout on the client part is correct, stating " Filters Sent: 'ATL' containing 3 bytes ", I can only understand that the issue comes from the server side and the alocation of the buffer size. Did I miss anything or did I mess up on the use of sizeof and strlen.

Comment: Remember that `strlen` doesn't include the string null-terminator in the length it returns. So the data you receive will not be null-terminated as a string. You either need to send the null-terminator as well, or in the receiver add it at the end.

Comment: Note if the socket is a streaming socket like TCP, don't count on getting the whole message or only one message in one call to `recv`. Streams don't respect your message boundaries. You'll get the message in the order you wrote it, but a stream will pack your messages into packets to minimize wastage and what you read out will be what's available at the time or if nothing's available, whatever's in the next packet up to the number of bytes you asked for.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But in my application, all messages are approximately the same size with a variation of more or less 50 bytes. I will try to send the size of the message first to set the buffer size and then receiving the message in the proper size.

Comment: That is an excellent strategy. A couple recommendations: When you send the message length, use a [fixed width integer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) to ensure the sender and receiver agree on the size of the length. Also ensure that the [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the length is known as well to defend against a difference of opinion on the default byte order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cout << recvbuf` is treating `recvbuf` as a null-terminated `char*` string, but there is no null terminator being sent by the client, and no null terminator being inserted by the server after the data received. So, `operator<<` ends up reading past the valid data, which is why you are seeing extra garbage being printed.

So, you can either:

- update the client to send the null terminator (just make sure the server's `recvbuf` is large enough to receive it):

```
const char* sendbuf = "ATL";
int sendbuflen = strlen(sendbuf) + 1; // <-- here
```

- add a null terminator artificially on the server side:

```
char recvbuf[4];

do {
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf)-1, 0);
    if (iResult > 0)
    {
        recvbuf[iResult] = '\0'; // <-- here
        printf("\nBytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        printf("Received Filters:");
        std::cout << recvbuf << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
```

- since `recv()` tells you how many bytes are actually received, simply use `ostream::write()` instead of `operator<<`, eg:

```
std::cout.write(recvbuf, iResult);
std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
```